# Breeze spatial query

Tags: sql-server, breeze, spatial

We need to run a spatial query and we are also using Breeze, and I understand that Breeze currently does not support spatial queries.  So I was wondering if it would be possible to pass a regular query to the controller using the regular Odata format; run the query and then UNION the results with a spatial query run directly against Entity Framework?

In this way, we can have the client prepare a demographic query and do a level one "filter" of the persons we are interested in, and then apply the spatial query to do a level two "filter".

Is this possible?  What would the syntax look like?

Thanks!!!!!

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Breeze cannot construct an OData filter on a spatial type but any Breeze WebApi/WebApi2 server can "return" spatial types.  So if your query result returns an entity or a projection containing a spatial type, it will be available on the client. ( The client side format is dependent on the JSON.NET formatter).

If this is acceptable, then you can use Breeze's NamedQuery facility to pass extra parameters to your server side query and use these to construct your own spatial filtering.

Hope this makes sense.